# How can the user only able to give rating for once? (vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My code is like this :

```
<div id="app">
    <p>Communication:</p>
    <star-rating :value="3" name="communication"></star-rating>
</div>
```

Demo and full code is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/swyuarc9/16/

I want when the user has given a rating, he could not give a rating again

So he can only give a rating once

How can I do it?

Comment: Well do you want to make it one session ? I mean If user reload page he would be able to rate it again, unless you use something like localStorage.

Comment: @Belmin Bedak, I mean when the user has given the rating, he could not give a rating again. If the page reload, he still could not give a rating

Answer (score 0):

```
<star-rating :value="3" name="communication" :exist="true"></star-rating>
```

You can set flag\property to your component, and use it decide to allow user set rating or not.